# Как подписаться на событие перехода в полноэкранный режим на Yandex Games?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-игры

Как подписаться на событие перехода в/из полноэкранного режима на Yandex Games?

Дело в том, что в [словесной игре](https://yandex.ru/games/play/147407), которую я опубликовал на Yandex Games, я подписан на такое событие и сдвигаю определенные кнопки при переходе в fullscreen:

```
var domElem = document.getElementById('fullDiv');

domElem.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', moveButtons);
domElem.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', moveButtons);
domElem.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', moveButtons);
// for ie11 attach to the document instead of the DOM element
document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', moveButtons);
```

А для Yandex Games этот способ не работает... В документации я нашел объект [screen.fullscreen.request](https://yandex.ru/dev/games/doc/dg/sdk/sdk-params.html)

[image: скриншот документации]

Но как на него подписаться, чтобы он вызывал мою функцию moveButtons? (я не эксперт по JavaScript, не совсем понимаю, как этот `Promise<void>` прикрутить к кастомной функции).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addEventListener("fullscreenchange")` не работет потому что в полноэкранный режим переходит не фрейм игры, а родительський  - окно Яндекс.Игры.

Можно самому по интервалу проверять поле `status` и в случае изменения запускать нужный код.

Вот моя реализация.

```
const fullscreenObserver = (() => {
  const callbacks = [];
  
  const subscribe = callback => callbacks.push(callback);
  const dispatch = newStatus => callbacks.forEach(callback => callback(newStatus));
  
  let lastStatus;
  setInterval(() => {
    const newStatus = ysdk.screen.fullscreen.status;
    if (lastStatus !== newStatus) {
      dispatch(newStatus);
      lastStatus = newStatus;
    }
  }, 300);
  
  return { subscribe };
})();

// ...

function moveButtons(fullscreen){
  console.log(fullscreen); // on | off
}

fullscreenObserver.subscribe(moveButtons);
```

Answer (score 0):

Поделюсь собственным решением -

```
YaGames
.init()
.then(ysdk => {
    console.log('Yandex SDK initialized');
    window.ysdk = ysdk;

    var fullscreenStatus = ysdk.screen.fullscreen.status;

    setInterval(function() {
        if (fullscreenStatus !== ysdk.screen.fullscreen.status) {
            fullscreenStatus = ysdk.screen.fullscreen.status;
            console.log("ysdk.screen.fullscreen.status has changed to: " + fullscreenStatus);
            moveButtons(fullscreenStatus === ysdk.screen.fullscreen.STATUS_ON);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

А `ysdk.screen.fullscreen.request` и `ysdk.screen.fullscreen.exit`, которые я упоминал в своём вопросе - они для смены полноэкранного режима, а не его наблюдения.